# Angular Material with $watch

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-menu id="user-status-menu" md-position-mode="{{vm.position}}" md-offset="{{vm.offset}}">
```

I want to update **md-position-mode** and **md-offset value** from controller dynamically.
but it's work only first time when page load.

How can update and make effect when value changed ?!

Comment: Are you updating the vm.position and vm.offset values in the controller? Can you share that code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First** view the snippet in **Full Page** view, its to the right of "Run Snippet". Click "Run Snippet" Then Click "Full Page"

1. Change `0 -5` to `0 50` moves down
2. Change `0 -5` to `50 -5` moves right
3. Change `target target` to `target-right target` and `0 -5` to `""` the menu is on the right

[**mdMenu**](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdMenu)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

myApp.controller('myController',
  function myController($scope, $mdDialog){
  $scope.vm = {
   "position": "target target",
    "offset": "0 -5"
  };
  
  var originatorEv;
  $scope.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
      originatorEv = ev;
      $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };
  
  $scope.announceClick = function(index) {
      $mdDialog.show(
        $mdDialog.alert()
          .title('You clicked!')
          .textContent('You clicked the menu item at index ' + index)
          .ok('Nice')
          .targetEvent(originatorEv)
      );
      originatorEv = null;
    };
  
});
```

```css
.menudemoMenuPositionModes .md-menu-demo {
  padding: 24px; }

.menudemoMenuPositionModes .menu-demo-container {
  min-height: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    Position: <input type="text" name="position" ng-model="vm.position">
    Offset: <input type="text" name="offset" ng-model="vm.offset">
    <p>$scope.vm = {{ vm | json }};</p>
    
      <div layout="column" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="100" flex="33" layout-align="center center">
        <p>Target mode with <code>md-offset</code></p>
        <md-menu md-position-mode="{{vm.position}}" md-offset="{{vm.offset}}">
          <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" aria-label="Open demo menu" ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
            Open
          </md-button>
          <md-menu-content width="4">
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in [1, 2]">
              <md-button ng-click="announceClick($index)"> <span md-menu-align-target>Option</span> {{item}} </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
          </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
      </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```